# Summary of ways you can control the request/response flow in play in controllers & actions

Tags: scala, playframework

Can someone summarize with a very short code snippet (or link to docs) the ways you can control/modify the request/response cycle in play. (scala version if that matters)

So far I know of:

1. Create a base controller that your other controllers will extend/inherit
   Use @Before and @After
   Will this work in the latest 2.2.2 version?
2. Action compositions http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaActionsComposition

What else is there?

Answer (score 1):

- Action Composition: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition
- The Global object: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal
- Interception with filters or `onRouteRequest`: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaInterceptors
- Filters vs Action composition: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaHttpFilters

The method with a base controller looks more like a dirty hack to me. Especially when using Play with Scala (in Java *everything* looks like a dirty hack :) )

Comment: what about controller and action level annotations?  Is that not supported in 2.2.x?   (Easy now, netty is written in java!)